# vba excel Find string, move to an offset location, copy dynamic range to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, range, offset

What I have been doing previously is manually selecting and then copy/paste raw data from a report into a sheet titled "ImportDump". From here I use VBA to select and copy the 11 ranges I am interested in across to specific locations in Sheet1 and Sheet2. I would explicitly state the ranges that the data occupy in the ImportDump sheet and copy them across. This worked but is no longer simple to do.

Instead, I plan to search for each table heading in Column A in the ImportDump sheet using the `Find` method, and then use the result of `Find`, plus an offset, as the starting position of a dynamic range. So for example, the string "Capital Premier" is found in A30, but the range I need starts in B33. I then need all rows down to the next blank cell in Column B, and all columns across to  the next blank column (data always finishes in Column J). And then repeat for all further 11 heading strings. The headings will all appear in Column A, all the tables will have the same offset from the search string result (3,1), and the same number of columns (9), but not necessarily the same number of rows.

I think I know how to do the search `IDump.Range("A1:A200").Find(What:="Capital Premier", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)`, and I'm pretty sure I can use `.End(xldown)` to select down to the next blank row, but I'm not sure how to combine all that with an offset to express the starting location of my dynamic range. Could someone please help me to solve this?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Your question is WAY too long and have WAY too much noise

Comment: Suppose you set `f=IDump.Range("A1:A200").Find(` then just do `f.offset()`

Comment: @Chris Munro is there the same amount of space between each table?

Comment: @aFast Yes, currently there is the same amount of space between each table in the raw data, but I'm not the one controlling that so I'm not sure I can assume that will always be true.

Comment: @findwindow Sure, I have done something very similar up to that point; so I can use the offset property to get the start location of the range i.e. `Set CapPrem = f.offset(3,1)`, which leads me to a cell in Column B. But then how do I reference that location in B to select all the columns to the right that hold data and all the rows down to the last row that holds data? When I've tried to use `Range(Range("CapPremRng"), Range("CapPremRng").End(xlDown)).Copy` it gives me Runtime error '1004'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit: I've found my ideal solution (unless someone comes up with something even better)**

This code combines a look at a table on one sheet ("Instructions") for a user-defined string, a search for the string in a separate sheet ("ImportDump" - a raw data dump), once the string is found it jumps to an offset cell location (3,1), finds the last row and last column before the next blank, selects the range outlined by the offset location, lastrow and lastcol, copies the range to a location (Sheet, then Cell) defined in the initial search table that corresponds to the search string. It then loops through all the rest of the user-defined strings until the last row of the table in the "Instructions" sheet, finding the ranges and pasting them into the corresponding predetermined locations. Thanks for everyone's input!

```
Sub ImportLeagueTables()

Dim r As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim IDump As Worksheet
Dim Instruct As Worksheet
Dim what1, where1, where2 As String
Dim TeamRng, TableRng, f, g As Range
Dim LastRowTeam As Long, Lastrow, Lastcol As Long

Set Instruct = Sheets("Instructions")
Set IDump = Sheets("ImportDump")
    LastRowTeam = Instruct.Range("M4").End(xlDown).Row

Set TeamRng = Instruct.Range("M4:O" & LastRowTeam)

i = 1

     For Each r In TeamRng.Rows 'rows to loop through

         what1 = TeamRng.Range("A" & i) 'the string to find
         where1 = TeamRng.Range("B" & i)
         where2 = TeamRng.Range("C" & i)

            Set f = IDump.Columns(1).Find(what1, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
            Set g = f.Offset(3, 1)
            Lastrow = g.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
            Lastcol = g.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

            Set TableRng = IDump.Range(g, IDump.Cells(Lastrow, Lastcol))

                TableRng.Copy
                Sheets(where1).Range(where2).PasteSpecial xlValues

            i = i + 1

         Next r

End Sub
```

**Original, less robust solution**: Ok, I've come up with a workable solution by explicitly defining the range with reference to the first cell i.e. `Set g = f.Offset(3, 1)` and `Set CapPremRng = g.Range("A1:I10")`, although that's not as elegant as I would like. Would prefer to use g to select all cells down and across until the next blank row/column.

Full code:

```
Sub DoMyJob()

Dim IDump As Worksheet
Dim f As Range
Dim g As Range
Dim CapPremRng As Range

Set IDump = Sheets("ImportDump")

Set f = IDump.Range("A1:A200").Find(What:="Capital Premier", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
Set g = f.Offset(3, 1)
Set CapPremRng = g.Range("A1:I10")

CapPremRng.Copy
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1" & LastRow).PasteSpecial xlValues

End Sub
```

Comment: So find last row and last column and plug that into `range`.

Comment: @findwindow That was the object of my question. I wish to know how to plug that into the range. I have `Lastrow = g.End(xlDown).Row
Lastcolumn = g.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column`. `Lastrow` gives me 42, as B42 is the last row of the table, Last column gives me 10 as Column J is the last column. But I have no idea how to plug that into the range to select the range I want. I keep either getting an blank range, or a 42 x 10 table, when I expect a 10 x 9 table. I'm sure there's something obviously wrong in my syntax, but I can't see it.

Comment: `g.Range("A1:I" & lastrow)`

Comment: @fixedwindow  That gives me a 42 x 10 table. Rather than selecting down to row 42 - which is what I want it to do - it is selecting down 42 rows. Am I defining Lastrow as the wrong type of object? - I've been defining it as Long.